# joining lists of lists into same index

Tags: python

I have two lists of lists that I am joining using:

```
list1 = [[],["1","3","4"],["0"],["1","2","5","4"]]
list2 = [["1","2","3"],["8","7","6"],[],["9","8","6","4"]]

for (v, c) in zip(list1, list2):
    joined_list =sorted(set(v + c))
```

This currently puts the values into the end of the list, I want it to go into the same index that they are currently in whats the best way to do this ?

EDIT: forgot that they are strings, the code is here
https://github.com/ishikawa-rei/EPRO-CALC/blob/master/massaging.py
its the first function and gets input of two lists

Comment: Please add example of input, output and expected output.

Comment: You're doing a `return` in the loop? That returns just the first result.

Comment: Your loop is setting `joined_list` for each `v, c` pair, so it's discarding all but the last pair.  Are you certain this is the code you're actually running?

Answer (score 0):

You are reassinging `joined_list` in every loop iteration.  You have to define the list before the loop and collect items as you iterate:

```
joined_list = []
for v, c in zip(list1, list2):
    joined_list.append(sorted(set(v + c)))
```

Or you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
joined_list = [sorted(set(v + c)) for v, c in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: this also puts everything into the end of the list rather than the index that they are in. When doing zip(list1,list2) it puts values in wrong index.

Comment: What is the output that you expect for your input?

Comment: I have two list of lists, if theres a value in list1 in the 17th list I want it to be added to a new list in new_list[17]. The data I have is to big to paste here but can be seen here https://github.com/ishikawa-rei/EPRO-CALC/blob/master/main.py

Comment: @dmnte But that's what this does. The values from the 17th lists in both `list1` and `list2` will be in the 17th list in `joined_list`

Comment: trying it on my data it doesnt for some reason. Im able to do it now but the code is preety ugly and slow, how im doing it is here: https://pastebin.com/izTY79PS

Answer (score 0):

You should be using append method instead.

```
joined_list = []
for (v, c) in zip(list1, list2):
    joined.append(sorted(set(v+c)))

print(joined)
```

This outputs the following:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8], [0], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: i tried this and it puts everything into the end of the list, also I made a mistake in question they are string not int

Comment: can you update your question with expected input and output.